# Using JenkinsFile pipeline to deploy a lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have created a JenkinsFile to load a jar file  onto AWS Lambda
As I understand in its load the jar file into an S3 bucket, then deploy it.
I want to stick with using a JenkinsFile loaded up into the pipeline.

so far using the S3 publisher plugin, I have the following

```
stage('load artifacts to S3'){
            agent any
            steps {
                s3Upload(bucket:"deploy-lambda-s3", workingDir:'target', includePathPattern:'my-lambda.jar');
            }
        }
```

Now i want to use the AWS Lambda Plugin to deploy the lambda. But I cant find the method. I was hoping for something such as

```
  s3Upload(bucket:"deploy-lambda-s3", FunctionName: "my-lambda", LambdaName: "myLambda")
```

I dont want to use script "aws lambda" i wuld prefer to use the functions provided.

Comment: You can check out the [AWS Lambda Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/aws-lambda/).

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to know what the function is. Java docs have a list of all the classes , the methods and paramters.
At the moment I am using aws cli  sh (script: "aws lambda update-function-code --function-name ${LAMBDA_FUCTION} --s3-bucket ${S3_BUCKET} --s3-key ${S3_KEY}", returnStdout: false)       But there has to be a method call similar to the one I am using to load a jar into S3                  s3Upload(bucket:"${S3_BUCKET}", workingDir:'target', includePathPattern:'${S3_KEY}');